# Should SPRT use explicit hypotheses or reflect observed differences in the data?

Tags: likelihood-ratio, sequential-analysis

Sequential Probability Ratio Testing (SPRT) compares the log-likelihood ratio of the observed data under the null and alternative hypotheses to thresholds based on desired alpha and beta levels.

I am new to using this method and want to confirm that **the null and alternative hypotheses should reflect the observed data rather than be hardcoded in before the data is observed**. I typically see hard coded hypotheses in the few vignettes I have found on the method, e.g. H_0: treat = .85, H_1: treat = .85 * 1.01, but it seems more appropriate to set the hypotheses based on the observed values in the data, e.g, H_0: treat = control, H_1: treat = control * 1.01, and I have done this below. This is primarily a sanity check with simulated data and code.

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

## Sequential Probability Ratio Testing [(SPRT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_probability_ratio_test)

SPRT allows you to peak at your data incessantly without compromising your test. You perform the test in 3 steps:

1. Set Stopping Thresholds
2. Set Explicit Null and Alternative Hypotheses
3. Compare LLR of your data under these hypotheses to your stopping thresholds

### Set Stopping Thresholds (a & b) for your test based on desired $\alpha$ and $\beta$ levels

$$a = log \frac{\beta}{1-\alpha}$$

```r
MY_ALPHA <- .05
MY_BETA <- .2
A <- log( MY_BETA / (1-MY_ALPHA) )
```

$$b = log \frac{1-\beta}{\alpha}$$

```r
B <- log( (1-MY_BETA) / MY_ALPHA )
```

### Set a pair of hypotheses about the parameter (i.e., treatment effect $\theta$) you are trying to estimate :

$H_0: \theta = 0\%$

$H_1: \theta = 101\ ITC\%$

```r
MDE <- 1.01 # minimum detectable effect of interest
```

Everyday we will tally the events and trials in the treatment and control groups, and we will compute the `log-likelihood ratio` of the accumulated data ($S_i$).

$$a<S_{i}<b: continue\ sampling$$

$$S_i\geq b: Accept\ H_1$$

$$S_i\leq a: Accept\ H_0$$

### Simulate Data from a Randmized Experiment

```r
set.seed(42)
DAYS <- 14
DAILY_N <- 1e3
BASERATE <- .85
MDE <- 1.02

df_sprt <- tibble(
    day = 1:DAYS,
    control_events = rbinom(n = DAYS, size = DAILY_N, 
                            prob = BASERATE),
    treat_events = rbinom(n = DAYS, size = DAILY_N, 
                          prob = BASERATE*MDE),
    control_trials = DAILY_N,
    treat_trials = DAILY_N
) %>% 
mutate(
    control_events = cumsum(control_events),
    treat_events = cumsum(treat_events),
    control_trials = cumsum(control_trials),
    treat_trials = cumsum(treat_trials),
    control_rate = control_events / control_trials,
    treat_rate = treat_events / treat_trials
)
```

### Compare LLR of your cumulative data to your stopping thresholds

```r
test_progress <- 
    df_sprt %>% 
    mutate(
        llr = 
            log(dbinom(x=treat_events, size=treat_trials, 
                   prob=control_rate*MDE)) - 
            log(dbinom(x=treat_events, size=treat_trials, 
                   prob=control_rate)),
        decision = case_when(
            llr >= B ~ "Reject Null Hy & Accept Alternative Hy",
            llr <= A ~ "Reject Alternative Hy & Retain Null Hy",
            TRUE ~ 'Keep Sampling'
        )
    )
```

### Plot Results

```r
test_progress %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = day, y = llr)) +
    geom_hline(
        yintercept = 
            c(A,B), 
            color = c('red', 'darkgreen')
    ) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line() + 
    annotate(
        x=10,y=A,
        label="Reject Alternative Hy & Retain Null Hy",
        vjust=-1, geom="text", color = 'red'
    ) + 
    annotate(
        x=10,y=B,
        label="Reject Null Hy & Accept Alternative Hy",
        vjust=1.5, geom="text", color = 'darkgreen'
    ) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = -10:20) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:20) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, 
          hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: It is invalid for a hypothesis to reflect the data.  What would be valid is to generate hypotheses from previous data and then to start over with new data to test those hypotheses.

Comment: @whuber Sorry, to be clear, my hypotheses was set before collecting data. I am hoping to confirm that null hy and alt hy in SPRT reflect the observed differences in the collected data just like traditional null hypothesis tests (e.g., fixed sample t-test)

Comment: I don't follow that.  The test results reflect the data.  The hypotheses are used to design the test and interpret the results.  Since the hypotheses are logically prior to the data, how could they possibly "reflect the observed differences"?

Comment: @whuber I have a priori set H_1 as treat_rate = control_rate * 1.01. So when I perform my test the likelihood of H_1 will reflect the observed rates in the treatment and control groups. This may be a point so obvious that it was not worth asking, but I was hard pressed to find clear examples of applying SPRT in practice. What examples I could find seemed to hard code baseline control rates into the analysis, e.g., H_1: treat = .85 * 1.01, this hardcoding would not reflect the observed rates in control, just the expected rate and this seemed off to me.